# Generating Shake Rules from Actions

Tags: shake-build-system

I would like find all of the 'Makefiles' in my project and then generate
Rules based them.
However, it looks like (purposely) nothing can escape an Action.
So, Instead I lifted my 'Makefile' scanner to the IO operation before the
shake function.

```
main = do
  makefiles <- findMakefiles
  shake skakeOptions $ generate_rules makefiles
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I don't think there's anything wrong with the current approach. The Shake package itself uses a similar approach for the built in Ninja and Makefile interpreters,
see [details about the Makefile interpreter](http://neilmitchell.blogspot.co.uk/2014/01/running-makefiles-with-shake.html)
or [the Sake interpreter](http://neilmitchell.blogspot.co.uk/2014/05/shake-as-dependency-library.html). As long as processing the Makefile is sufficiently quick not to
matter (which it usually is) then you are basically writing an
interpreter for your custom build syntax using Shake, which works
nicely.

There are a couple of reasons to avoid that approach, for example, if the processing of the Makefile is expensive, or if the Makefile itself has other dependencies. In that situation you can use a combination of `newCache` to parse the Makefile once, and `addOracle` so rules can depend on the subset of the Makefile they require. However, that approach is tricker to get right, since it basically forces a layer of indirection, and you have to make some assumptions about how `generate_rules` works. The [ghc-make](https://github.com/ndmitchell/ghc-make/blob/master/Build.hs) package uses this technique (see the "makefile" rule and call to `newCache`), and the `usingConfigFile` function from the Shake package uses the same `newCache`/`addOracle` pattern.

Sticking with the original approach, there is somewhere slightly different you can put your `findMakefiles` step. You can do:

```
main = shakeArgsWith shakeOptions [] $ \_ -> xs -> do
    makefiles <- findMakefiles
    let rules = generate_rules makefiles
    if null xs then rules else withoutActions rules >> want xs
```

This has the advantage that you can easily add command line flags to figure out where to find the Makefile, or options for processing it. Both the Ninja and Makefile systems in Shake support that, using `--makefile=FILE` to override the default. Even if you don't want to move `generate_rules`, you might want to replace `shake` with `shakeArgs` in your original example, which will provide you with command line handling.